# Is there a way in Excel to display a certain cell if another contains specific text?

Tags: excel

Hi everyone i have an excel document which is a list of people and the activities these people do, like:

```html
People programmming swimming golf
David       Yes        Yes    No
Lucy        Yes        No     Yes
Martin      No         Yes    Yes
```

I need to have a list of activities counting the number of people that do that activity and theyr names. For example:

```html
Programming 2 people
     David
     Lucy

Swimming 2 people
     David
     Martin
```

I know i accomplish with an IF function but i don't want blank spaces between names, so i need a function that: if the person does the activity the name is added but if not, it checks the next person.

What can i use?

Comment: Have you considered using a filter? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean that you don't need blank spaces between names? It will be better if you can show the desired result in terms of excel cells in the question. You can attach screenshot.

Comment: Yes filtering can be a good option but i was looking for a more dinamic way because filter needs to be updated manually if i change a value or if i Add another person.

Comment: I think you are looking for `Pivot Tables`. Have you tried them?

Comment: Yes, Pivot Table can help but i was looking if there is a way to accomplish that with a function

Answer (score 0):

You seem fairly hell bent on the VBA approach and if that's the case, copy and paste the below code into a new module within your workbook ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransformData()
    Dim rngCells As Range, lngCol As Long, lngRow As Long, strHeader As String
    Dim lngWriteRow As Long, objDict As Scripting.Dictionary, arrNames() As String
    Dim objDestSheet As Worksheet, i As Long, x As Long

    Set objDestSheet = Worksheets("Transformed")
    Set objDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set rngCells = Selection

    objDestSheet.Cells.Clear

    With rngCells
        For lngCol = 2 To .Columns.Count
            strHeader = .Cells(1, lngCol)

            ' Reset the array in case no names are found to have a yes next to them.
            ReDim Preserve arrNames(0)
            arrNames(0) = ""

            For lngRow = 2 To .Rows.Count
                If Left(UCase(.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)), 1) = "Y" Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrNames(UBound(arrNames) + 1)
                    arrNames(UBound(arrNames)) = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
                End If
            Next

            objDict.Add strHeader, arrNames
        Next
    End With

    With objDestSheet
        For i = 0 To objDict.Count - 1
            strHeader = objDict.Keys(i)
            arrNames = objDict.Items(i)

            strHeader = strHeader & " " & UBound(arrNames) & " people"

            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
            .Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = strHeader

            For x = 1 To UBound(arrNames)
                lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
                .Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = arrNames(x)
            Next

            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
        Next
    End With

    objDestSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

... then create a sheet in your workbook called **Transformed**.

Add a reference to the below library ...

[image]

Now select your matrix of data and run the macro.

[image]

I hope it works for you.